# How do I describe the growth of something that scales by a factorial?

Tags: terminology, factorial

I just wrote a [blog post](http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/overwhelmed-by-choice/) and wasn't sure how to word a particular sentence. Say I have the following function:

\begin{equation}
f(x) = x^2
\end{equation}

Then I can say that the value of *f(x)* grows **quadratically** with *x**. Similarly with this function:

\begin{equation}
f(x) = e^x
\end{equation}

...I could say that *f(x)* grows **exponentially** with *x*. But what about this?

\begin{equation}
f(x) = x!
\end{equation}

Do I say that *f(x)* grows "factorially"? What's the proper term?

---

<sub>*I worded this wrong at first. It should be right now. <strike>Wait, is that even right? Or would "exponentially" imply *f(x) = k<sup>x</sup>*? Should the first term be "quadratically" instead?</strike></sub>

Comment: $f(x) = x^2$ grows quadratically with $x$. $f(x) = e^x$ grows exponentially.

Comment: @Moron: Thanks, you pointed that out just as I started to realize my mistake (see my edits—I've now corrected that part).

Comment: I think you mean $e^x$ where you wrote $e^2$.

Comment: @Rahul: Yes I did, thanks for pointing that out! (Man, clearly it pays to proofread your math.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Stirling's formula,

$$n! \times e^n \approx Cn^{n + 1/2}$$

I am not sure if there is a name for that kind of growth. It is super-exponential and might be enough to get the point across, I suppose.

btw, $f(x) = x^2$ is said to grow *quadratically*, not exponentially.

Comment: @Moron: You forgot about the $e^{-n}$-term in Stirling's formula.

Comment: @Rasmus: Yes, was editing :-)Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Well, $n^n$ can be described as **tetration**, in which case it could be denoted ${}^2n$. Not sure how that word could be turned into an adjective though, and it's not exactly widely used I guess :)

Comment: @Will: Yes, but $n!$ is $n^{n+1/2}$ divided by $e^n$, so it is not exactly tetration... There is also that $\sqrt{n}$ factor.

Comment: I'd say this, combined with Will's comment, answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Dan: I'd still prefer factorially, however.

Comment: @Rasmus: Oh, that's what I went with.